# Image swapping, data hiding, javascript and SEO

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a product web page.  This product page has multiple attributes such as size and color.  I'm working on building an image swap script (jQuery) that will swap the main image on the page based on events.

Easy enough and there's a million tutorials how to do that.

Where this gets less trivial is the attributes.  I want to be able to swap images based on the aforementioned attributes selected.

**First**, the page will display an image that has been set as "default" for a given product.

**Second**, if someone clicks "size: large", it will show the image that's set for size large.

**Third**, if someone clicks "color: red", it will pull the "large : red" image and swap it for the main image.

**Fourth**, if someone now clicks "size : small", it will fetch the "small : red" image file.

**Fifth**, if someone now clicks "color : blue", it will fetch the "small : blue" image file.

You get the idea.

I have a database with the size:color table.  The question is, what is the best way to get this data in the HTML page so I can load it into JavaScript?

I want to avoid an AJAX call because of the extra network overhead and the page load will have already accessed the database and gathered all the data, I don't want to call the database *again* and have it do all that work a second time.

I could hide the data with CSS (display:none) in the liked elements, but I would be concerned with SEO.  There's a bit of data to hide.  There's thumbnail image URLs, standard size and large size.  I certainly wouldn't want to save it as JSON format like that and just display:none.

I thought maybe saving it in HTML comments and using the jQuery comments() plug-in.  I have concerns of speed and feasibility.

Any thoughts on how people best store data in the HTML file to access with JavaScript to build some nice page experience effects?

---- EDIT ----

Having slept on this, I'm thinking that I'm over thinking this whole thing.  This whole time I'm trying to figure out how can I add all this product image information into HTML so JavaScript could use it add effects, when all I think I need to do is just have my PHP spit out the image/attribute table as a JavaScript object so I can use it.  Instead of trying to figure out some way to re-load it from HTML.  Which is just over thinking the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spit out the page with a JavaScript block that contains the data for the product in JSON format.

Alternately you can get clever with class names and put the data in there: `red_A12345` would parse out to *red image = "A12345.jpg"*

Comment: Actually, that is what I usually do but since there are so many variables in the set of data, class names just didn't work.  Partially due to the need to tokenize the string to fit all the data in and having to have multiple class names associated to that string, that it just didn't seem to be practical for this case.  I have implemented PHP adding a JavaScript variable of the data and that has worked quite well and I think might have some other uses for heavier data-sets.

Answer (score 0):

see my edited comment -

I found that creating a JS variable/object via PHP worked quite well for passing the data to JS so I could create a JS app that did the image swapping complexity as described above.

I use Zend and jQuery as PHP/JS frameworks so the code sample will reflect this.  But the concept will work for any development platform:

```
// parse the object into Json in PHP to pass to JavaScript, using Zend_Json
$jsonSource = Zend_Json::encode($dataObject);

// parse the Json in jQuery as a JavaScript script
$script = 'var imgTable = jQuery.parseJSON(\'' . $jsonSource . '\');';

// append the script to my Zend_Framework template so it prints out
$this->view->headScript()->appendScript($script, $type);
```

In addition, I think I'll be looking into the practicality of doing this for building a dynamic check-box web-form that will enable/disable form options based the current inputs and if there are any results available for future options, based on current options selected.